# Active connections on web farm

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, network-programming

I'm trying to build a simple chat with `websockets`. I'm also displaying the current active users in the chat, and here is where the problems start: we use a web farm.

A user can connect through a `loadbalancer` with a server. When a new connection hits a server, it increases a counter in a `SQL database` and notifies the other servers in the farm through `rabbit MQ`.

All other servers fetch the new data and send that number back to their connected users.

If an user disconnects, the same will happen: The server decreases the counter in the SQL database and through `rabbit MQ` all other servers will know about this.

But, what will happen when a server dies? **for example**, If 10 users will be connected with this server. When that server goes down, all the users are disconnected, but that is not updated in the database anymore.

What's the best solution to get the total amount of active users in a web farm? And notifying the users when this amount has changed?

Thanks in advance!

Oh btw, we're using `signalr`

Answer (score 1):

I think the typical way to deal with nodes asynchronously disconnecting from a mesh is to implement a heartbeat/keep-alive mechanism. In this case the heartbeat message would be between servers and there must also be an accessible record of which users are connected to which server. When a server does not produce a heartbeat for a period of time, then all other servers can update their records and mark all the users associated with the server as disconnected.

Looks like you may have a few options on how to keep track of users (SQL database or every server listens a Rabbit MQ message). As far as the heartbeat, you can implement it yourself or try to see if the laodbalancer's detection method can be utilized.